# PDF to B64 using mPDF

Tags: php, pdf, mpdf

I'm using the mPDF library to convert a html into a PDF file. But i need an extra step and that is converting the PDF file to base64. Currently I have this co:

```
require_once('lib/mpdf.php');

$mpdf = new mPDF('c','A4');
$mpdf->writeHTML('<div>"Hello Wolrd!!"</div>');

echo base64_encode($mpdf);
```

The require is for the mPDF library, then I create the pdf file and I0m trying to convert it into base 64 but the  $mpdf variable is not a string so the function base64_encode is not working. Can someone help me with this. Thanks

Comment: Why you need to `echo` base64? mPDF has own Output class.

Answer (score 6):

Try below:

```php
require_once('lib/mpdf.php');

$mpdf = new mPDF('c','A4');
$mpdf->writeHTML('<div>"Hello Wolrd!!"</div>');

echo base64_encode($mpdf->Output('', 'S'));
```

By the way, you should upgrade to the recent Mpdf 8.0 if possible. It looks like you're using an old version.

Comment: I tried the above example not work for me, when I decode and save the code as pdf  file and run it, gives me a blank pdf file.

Let me know the solutions, I want to save the password-protected PDF file and send it as base64 encoded in API response.